# UIScrollView with a background set to the blurred image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that shows certain images based on an index. When an image loads, I want to set the background of the `UIScrollView` to the blurred version of that image. 
Right now I have a container view that houses the `scrollView`, and I've been trying to add a blurred `subView` to the container but it's not working out. If I just add the subview it gets rendered over the `scrollView` which id obviously no good, and If I add the `subView` and send it to back then I don't see any blurred effect at all.

Is this the right approach or is there a better way to achieve the effect I'm going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said "and If I add the subview and send it to back then I don't see any blurred effect at all."

To sort it out, You may try changing the background color of Scrollview to clearColor.

Comment: It should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Actually, I am not able to comment on user question's as it requires 50 reputation.Hopefully this will solve his problem and act as an answer! :)